# Why there is a unique $c$ s.t. $f(c)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ derivable such that $f'(x)\geq 7$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Show that there is a unique $c\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f(c)=0$.

**My try**
The unicity of such a $c$ is clear by the fact that $f'(x)>0$ and thus $f$ is one to one. Therefore, if a such $c$ exist, it is unique.

Now I want to prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty }f(x)=-\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=+\infty $. (The fact that there is $\ell_1,\ell_2\in\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty ,\infty \}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty }f(x)=\ell_{1,2}$ comes from the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing). So I suppose that $\ell_1\in\mathbb R$. Then there is an $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|>\frac{|\ell|}{2}$ if $x>M$. But how can I get a contradiction now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l_1 \in \Bbb{R}$, then there is some $M \in \Bbb{R}$ such that
$$x> M \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ l_1-1<f(x)<l_1+1$$
this implies that $-2 \le f(x+1)-f(x) \le 2$ for all $x>M$. Fix such an $x$.

By the mean value theorem there exists some $c \in (x,x+1)$ such that $f'(c) = f(x+1)-f(x)$ so you have
$$ f'(c) \leq 2<7$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(0)=b$, and let $x\gt 0$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we have 
$$\frac{f(x)-b}{x-0}=f'(k_x)$$
for some $k_x$ between $0$ and $x$. It follows that $f(x)-b\ge 7x$, and therefore $f(x)\ge b+7x$.  It is now clear that if $x$ is large enough, then $f(x)\gt 0$.

A similar argument shows that if $x$ is large enough negative, then $f(x)\lt 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the Mean value theorem to understand the following expression $$f(x)-f(0)$$ when $x\to +\infty$ and $x\to -\infty$.